# ng-repeat dynamic array name

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible to achieve dynamic array name, something like `friends+$index`. For example:

```
ng-repeat="friend in {{'friends'+$index}}"
```

The aim is to loop through different arrays: friends1 & friends2.
I tried everything, any combination, but without success. I also never came across to appropriate answers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide more code? where you have _friends1, friends2_?

Comment: What about putting the friends1, friends2, etc. in an array and then nesting the ng-repeats, one inside the other?

Comment: you can use array `friends` like `friends[$index]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/jigardafda/gw7f1qq0/1/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="(name, value) in frndslist">
            {{name}}
            <div ng-repeat="item in value.list">
                {{item}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapp',[]);

myApp
    .controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {

        $scope.frndslist = {
            'friend1': {
                name: 'x1 frnd',
                list: [
                    "1.some1",
                    "1.some2"
                ]
            },
            'friend2': {
                name: 'x2 frnd',
                list: [
                    "2.some1",
                    "2.some2"
                ]
            }  
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:

The HTML:

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="AppController as controller">
    <ul ng-repeat="friend in friends[index]">
        <li>{{friend}}</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    var application = angular.module("App",[]);

    application.controller("AppController",function($scope){
        friends1  =["Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4"];
        friends2  =["Name5", "Name6", "Name7"];
        $scope.friends  = new Array();
        $scope.friends.push(friends1);
        $scope.friends.push(friends2);
        //.......
        $scope.index = 0; // in this example it can be 0 or 1
    });
```

Comment: Well, how can I do if I am trying to combine 2 string values? For example `ng-repeat = "a in (name + 'List')"`. The name string value in this expression. `JonnyList`, `henryList`. How can I do that?